# Upgrade the JQuery mobile 1.7.1 framework to the new 1.1

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-mobile, stylesheet

I want to upgrade my JQuery mobile app from the previous version to the new one. Here is a link to the new [JQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/blog/2012/04/13/announcing-jquery-mobile-1-1-0/)

A big mistake i made is that I did tons off changes on the jquery mobile stylesheet. But on the javascripts I didn't change anything.

At the moment I have this in my Header

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" /> 
    <title>Selligent Mobile</title> 
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="images/app-icon.png"/>  
    <!-- CSS includes -->
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <!--<link href="css/jquery.mobile.simpledialog.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://dev.jtsage.com/cdn/simpledialog/latest/jquery.mobile.simpledialog.min.css" />
    <!-- Script includes -->    

    <script src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script> 
    <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/SelligentMobile.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.mobile.simpledialog2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>
```

Anybody got an idea how I can properly do this ?

Kind regards.

Answer (score 0):

I stripped out the structures, and themes and left them alone. I broke them out into structure, and core theme css. These hold the majority of the main css

I created a custom file that holds both my new themes, and custom css that I needed. This way when I go in to compare the versions I still estimate an hour or two to compare items because new additions may need to be made to my custom (loading is a good example)

The tricky part is if the structure changes in the themes you still have to reconcile with your custom theme to make sure no new additions exist.

- structure.css - This holds basic structure of the JQM (I also have a 
  custom       reset.css at the very top to  - it
  could be broken  out but I choose to just override the existing one there)
- core-themes.css  - Holds the core themes a,b,c,d,e
- custom-themes - f,g,h,i,j,k,l - etc..
- custom-css - contains very specific overrides